# SharePoint Server 2019 Training

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

I was wondering if anyone knows of any training or tutorials for SharePoint 2019 on-prem? I was hoping to find something that covers the server aspect as well as the front end of the application. Any videos or Certification paths would be great! Most of the stuff I find are related to SharePoint online..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an introduction to SharePoint Server in Microsoft's official documents. Many features are interlinked, you can view the features you know, and note that the applicable version is indicated in the document：
[Getting started with SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/getting-started)

In addition, here is a simple video for beginners, if you are interested:
[Microsoft SharePoint 2019 - Full Tutorial for Beginners [+ Overview]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=odixpcyqOgQ)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you think my suggestion is helpful, you could mark it as an answer. :)